# PHP creates relative link issue

Tags: php, hyperlink, relative-path

I have some PHP code which creates a cookie and saves part of the URL as a value, then recalled to be part of a link. Problem is doesn't really matter what I do the link includes a relative path when I need it to go to a different domain.

```
if (!(isset($_COOKIE['my_cookie']) || isset($_COOKIE['other_cookie']))) {
    if (is_page([2641,2998,2949])) {

    $this_cookie = "my_cookie";

    $cookie_value = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
    : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $path = "/";

    setcookie($my_cookie, strstr($cookie_value, '?'), time() + (86400 * 28), $path);

    $url_link = "https://newdomain/" . $cookie_value;
    }
```

cookie_value is '?myaddress/tobe/included'

Link becomes: https://newdomain/https://oldomain/?myaddress/tobe/included

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? That there's another `https:/` in the url link?

Comment: Maybe use a correct format? `https:/newdomain/` -> `https://newdomain/`

Comment: @kerbholz Excuse the typos. I edited them. For whatever reason the link just wants to include the current URL(oldomain) when needs to go to another webpage/address (newdomain). It spits out both URLS

Comment: You say that `$cookie_value` is `?myaddress/tobe/included`, but that can't be right - you are setting it to a full address on lines 7-8 of the posted code.

Comment: @zenzelezz yeah so i grab the whole address then trim it off when setting the cookie

Comment: No, you don't - `strstr()` does not modify the variable you pass it; it only returns a new string - so `$cookie_value` is never modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed the issue.

```
 $ppc_value = strstr((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
        ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] 
        : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');
```